# Python compile error when using binding C++

Tags: python, c++, arrays, binding, ns-3

I'm trying to implement an array in my C++ simulation (this coding provided is to have 2 values in one network packet field).

This is my variable declaration (in the header):

```
 Ptr<Name> m_names [2];
```

This is my function declaration (in the header):

```
void SetName (unsigned which, Ptr<Name> name);
void SetName (unsigned which, const Name &name);
```

Source file:

```
void Interest::SetName (unsigned which, Ptr<Name> name)
{
    if (which < 2)
    {
        m_names[which] = name;
    }
}

void Interest::SetName (unsigned which, const Name &name)
{
    if (which < 2)
    {
        m_names[which] = Create<Name> (name);
    }
}
```

The way I call this is like this (in my main file):

```
interest->SetName (0, nameWithSequence);
interest->SetName (1, nameWithNextSequence);
```

As a result, it gives an error like this:

```
src/ndnSIM/bindings/ns3module.cc: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_PyNs3NdnData_SetName__0(PyNs3NdnData*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject**)’:
src/ndnSIM/bindings/ns3module.cc:8418:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘ns3::ndn::Data::SetName(ns3::Ptr<ns3::ndn::Name>)’
src/ndnSIM/bindings/ns3module.cc:8418:62: note: candidates are:
./ns3/ndn-data.h:60:3: note: void ns3::ndn::Data::SetName(unsigned int, ns3::Ptr<ns3::ndn::Name>)
./ns3/ndn-data.h:60:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

The question is what is the correct way to declare the correct statement?

**EDIT**:
I have found some of the Python definitions to bind my C++ code (SetName)

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name == "_interest":
        return object.__setattr__ (self, name, value)

    elif name == "name":
        if value is None:
            return self._interest.SetName (ns.ndnSIM.ndn.Name ())
        elif isinstance (value, Name):
            return self._interest.SetName (value._name)
        elif isinstance (value, ns.ndnSIM.ndn.Name):
            return self._interest.SetName (value)
        elif isinstance (value, str):
            return self._interest.SetName (ns.ndnSIM.ndn.Name (value))
        else:
            raise ValueError ("Invalid name parameter")
```

Comment: You are missing `which` parameter in `GetName` and `GetNamePtr` definition. Is it same in real code also?

Comment: @Naveen hi, sorry for the mistake.i had edited it and please comment

Comment: It would be useful if you provide some information about error (line with error) AND what do you want as the result?

Comment: At function `const Name& Interest::GetName (unsigned which) const` what do you return if `which >= 2`? Nothing?

Comment: Why does GetName() return void in your header but const Name& in your source?

Comment: @Schollii purpose of my GetName is to have two values get from SetName and name is const. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @mexus actually there many errors regarding this since it is related with wire configuration but most of it is the same. i think the error shows that Getname is wrongly specified. as far as i understand which it will be never more than two since i declare the size of array is only two. Correct me if i am wrong over here

Comment: BTW, what is `Name`? Haven't you forgot a semicolon at the end of a function declaration `void GetName (unsigned which)`? And it probalby should return `const Name&` rather than `void`: `const Name& GetName(unsigned which);`

Comment: @mexus my fault..already edit it here (it has ; in coding). Name is another class which will check the value that entered in my main source file (Name is const). This is some of the error example rc/ndnSIM/bindings/ns3module.cc:16470:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘ns3::ndn::Interest::SetName(ns3::Ptr<ns3::ndn::Name>)’
src/ndnSIM/bindings/ns3module.cc:16470:62: note: candidates are:
./ns3/ndn-interest.h:65:3: note: void ns3::ndn::Interest::SetName(unsigned int, ns3::Ptr<ns3::ndn::Name>)
./ns3/ndn-interest.h:65:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided

Comment: @user3085445 well.. it still has different declarations in header and in source: `void GetName (unsigned which);` vs `const Name& GetName (unsigned which) const;`

Comment: @mexus oh man..many copy errors here.so sorry..i had a check and edited already..please comment

Comment: Please indicate line # where error occurs. Comments should not be used as thread. Please put your clarifications in your question.

Comment: @Schollii i put the error thrown in the question above. Appreciate if you have any ideas or suggestion..thanks

Comment: The error message you posted (I reformated as it was unreadable) indicates that you are making a call of the form `interest->SetName(name)` rather than `interest->SetName(0, name)`, perhaps in the wrapper code that exposes your C++ to Python. However you don't mention anything about Python in your post. How is this wrapper generated, is it via SWIG?

Comment: @Schollii yes, ndnsim simulator run on ns3 (the one im using now) use pyhton binding. is it that what you say is im wrongly declare the array?or there are something else missing?thanks

Comment: @Schollii i have edited my question above and i did found the pyhton coding but i dont have any idea how to solve this. Please help and give suggestion. thank you

Comment: I've shown you what to look for now I think it is time you dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. let me just give you an example.
I assume `Ptr` acts something like `std::shared_pointer`, and `Name` like a `std::string` (at least for an example purposes).

First of all, i'd recommend using `std::array` instead of a c-style array. But that's not really neccesary.
Second. If you plan `m_names` to be an array of a fidex size, you can throw an exception when accessing to a non-existent member.

Here is some code.
Header (test.h):

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <array>

typedef std::shared_ptr<std::string> pString;

struct A{
protected:
    static constexpr size_t array_size = 2;
    std::array<pString, array_size> m_names;
    static void CheckRange(size_t);
public:
    void SetName(size_t id, const std::string& name);
    void SetName(size_t id, const pString& name);

    const std::string& GetName(size_t id) const;
    const pString& GetNamePtr(size_t id) const;
};
```

Source:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <exception>

void A::SetName(size_t id, const pString &name){
    CheckRange(id);
    m_names[id] = name;
}

void A::SetName(size_t id, const std::string& name){
    CheckRange(id);
    m_names[id] = std::make_shared<std::string>(name);
}

const std::string& A::GetName(size_t id) const{
    CheckRange(id);
    if (!m_names[id])
            throw std::logic_error("Pointer is not initialized");
    return *(m_names[id].get());
}

const pString& A::GetNamePtr(size_t id) const {
    CheckRange(id);
    return m_names[id];
}
```

And here is an example of a `CheckRange` function:

```
void A::CheckRange(size_t id){
    if (!(id < array_size))
            throw std::logic_error("ID should be < " +
              std::to_string(array_size));
}
```

This code with some tests: http://ideone.com/rUvVhH

### Hint

`if (m_names[id])` checks if `m_names[id]` contains a valid pointer (e.g. not `nullptr`). I suppose `Ptr` has some similar functionality.
And I believe `std::make_shared<T>(...)` is similar to `Create<T>(...)`.

Well, as for me, this is more or less correct way to retrieve array content :)
If something is too complicated I'll try to make it easier to understand.
You are welcomed to ask if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

The error is at compile time in the Python binding code. So,

1. If the wrote the binding (wrapper) code yourself (using Python C API or boost::python), you must find where you define SetName binding, it is missing a parameter.
2. If binding is automatically generated by some tool (like SWIG or SIP), you have to find where the SetName binding is defined: this is what the wrapper tool will use to figure out what code to generate, the mistake is in that definition.

The Python code that you added to your post, **setattr**, indicates clearly that the self._interest.SetName(obj) calls are wrong: your C++ shows that SetName takes two parameters. If **setattr** is generated by some tool (ns3?) you have to find how it does this to give it the proper definition of SetName so that **setattr** will have proper call.